# unable to translate from Arabic to English Google translate free api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using nodeJS and this google URL to translate query: 
from English to Arabic works fine

http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=ar&dt=t&q=Hello

but when changing URL Translation from Arabic to English

[http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ar&tl=en&dt=t&q=مرحبا](http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ar&tl=en&dt=t&q=%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7)

returns invalid output "E1 ('" as a translation

while hitting above URL from the browser will return correct output, Here is my code

```
const request = require('request');

let endPoint = null;

if (language == 'english') {
    endPoint = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ar&tl=en&dt=t&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q="+text;
} else {
    endPoint = 'http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=ar&dt=t&q=' + text;
}
return request(endPoint, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Below is the output

```
[
  [
    [
        "مرحبا",
        "Hello",
        null,
        null,
        1
    ]
  ],
  null,
  "en"
]




[
  [
    [
        "E1 ('",
        "E1-('",
        null,
        null,
        3
    ]
  ],
  null,
  "ar"
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It worked for me

```
let text = "مرحب"
let endPoint = 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ar&tl=en&dt=t&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=' + encodeURIComponent(text);
request(endPoint, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```